# Writing multiple files concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to write 100 files in a parallel way.

There is a list `data` and items in it should be written to separate files. I've tried `concurrent.futures` but it didn't work(nothing in files).

```
data = ['a','b','c']

def write2file(i):
    outhandles[i].write(data[i])

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    executor.map(write2file,range(s,e))
```

Expected results:

```
file1.txt:'a',
file2.txt:'b',
...
```

Comment: *It does not work* means nothing. Please say what happens: syntax error, run time error (give the exact message and the stacktrace), unexpected result (describe actual and expected behaviour), other (say what).

Answer (score 0):

Put your data into a Queue object, then use threads to pop items off of the queue in parallel. This should help and thread-safe depending on your logic and how you are combining the files.